# Does PhoneGap generates an IPA file that is compatible with all iOS devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, phonegap

I have developed an a .ipa file for iOS from https://build.phonegap.com. It has sucessfully developed. I have a doubt. Does it work with all iOS device? How can I install an IPA file to iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Can you create ipa file using the valid certificates and profile ?
If yes then the ipa is the valid.

After creating the ipa you can create the download link using [this](http://www.diawi.com) website.
In this website you will upload your ipa file and then generate the link and then you will open that link in your iOS device and it will be install the application in your register device.